# Why can't you make conditional assignment in short hand IF statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, shorthand

I'm trying to update softcount for my Blackjack game to account for Aces being played (value 11 or 1). When using the short-form IF statement, why is the first line of code incorrect, but the second line is okay to use? Is this type of if statement limited?

```
(counter > 1) ? (softcount+=1) : (softcount+=value); // bad


softcount += (counter > 1) ? 1 : value; // good
```

Comment: It is not a shorthand if-statement, so your premise is wrong to start.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary has to be seen as a way to evaluate something and not as a way to apply a processing.
So it expects some expressions after `?` but you wrote statements : `softcount+=1` and  `(softcount+=value)` in the first code.
In the second code, it is ok because you specified two expressions : `1` and `value`.

Besides do you really find this code a short hand ?

```
(counter > 1) ? (softcount+=1) : (softcount+=value); // bad
```

You repeat the increment part.

What you want in your case is just :

```
if (counter > 1) { softcount+=1;} else {softcount+=value;)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simply how the language is defined.

Only certain expressions - statement expressions - can be made into a statement by adding `;`. (Statement expression + `;` is an *expression statement*).

From [JLS Sec 14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8):

```
ExpressionStatement:
  StatementExpression ;

StatementExpression:
  Assignment 
  PreIncrementExpression 
  PreDecrementExpression 
  PostIncrementExpression 
  PostDecrementExpression 
  MethodInvocation 
  ClassInstanceCreationExpression
```

Conditional expressions are not statement expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It is called ternary operator, it is used when you simply want to return a value based on condition. It's main purpose is to avoid if else for simple avaluations. In your case you should use if else.